# Driver for jdbc not found (only on servlet)

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, jdbc

I have a problem connecting to MySQL databse from servlet. Here is my connection code

```
private static void connectToDatabase(){
    try{
        static Connection conn = null;
        static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/database?userinfo"; 
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        System.out.println("Connected");
    } catch(ClassNotFoundException wyjatek) {
        System.out.println("Problem ze sterownikiem");
    } catch(SQLException wyjatek) {
        System.out.println("SQLException: " + wyjatek.getMessage());
        System.out.println("SQLState: " + wyjatek.getSQLState());
        System.out.println("VendorError: " + wyjatek.getErrorCode());
    }
}
```

and doGet

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    String param = request.getParameter("lookFor");

    out.println("TEST");

    connectToDatabase();
 }
```

and everytime I'm getting this

```
SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/database?userinfo
SQLState: 08001
VendorError: 0
```

I put the mysql-connector-java-5.1.27-bin in
        webapps\WEB-INF\lib
and
        apache-tomcat-7.0.55\lib

and it's still the same. In the desktop version of application everything works fine. It's happening only on servlet.

Comment: which jar did you put in tomcat/lib?

Comment: Only putting mysql-connector-java-5.1.27-bin in lib wont work , have you added in classpath ?

Comment: Shouldn't this be configured via the app/container XML?

Comment: Have tried calling `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")` _before_ calling `DriverManager.getConnection(url)`?

Comment: @scarywombat mysql-connector-java-5.1.27-bin.jar

Comment: @Jack OK, thanks. It worked. But why code like above is working on desktop version? I'm just curious

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic problem is

Your first step should be registering the Driver using this

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

Then try to get connection from DriverManager using this

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
```

I guess you are doing it the reverse way